# vscode c# debugger missing routes in asp.net mvc core app

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-code, asp.net-core-mvc

The debugger in the c# extension for visual studio code seems to alter how routing works;  if I run the app with dotnet run, all is well but if I use the debugger, certain routes are ignored.

Response using dotnet run

[image: Response using dotnet run]

Response using c# debugger (falling through to an app.Run(...);)

[image: Response using c# debugger]

As best I can tell, there's nothing in the config that should affect this.

Program.cs

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .CaptureStartupErrors(true)
            .UseSetting("detailedErrors","true")
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()       
            .AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>                        
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDbContext"))
                );

        services.AddMvc();
    }    

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory
            .AddDebug()
            .AddConsole()
            .AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics();

        var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Startup>();

        logger.LogInformation(1, "Logging in Configure");
        logger.LogInformation(1, $"ConnectionString: {Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDbContext")}");

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();    

        app.UseMvc(routes => {
            routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        app.Run(async context => {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync($"Hello World:  The current environment is {env.EnvironmentName}, the current value is {Configuration["MyEnvironment"]}");
        });
    }
}
```

launch.json

```
    {
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
        "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "launch",
        "preLaunchTask": "build",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}\\src\\web\\bin\\Debug\\netcoreapp1.0\\web.dll",
        "args": [],
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}\\src\\web",
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
        "launchBrowser": {
            "enabled": true,
            "args": "${auto-detect-url}",
            "windows": {
                "command": "cmd.exe",
                "args": "/C start ${auto-detect-url}"
                },
            "osx": {
                "command": "open"
                },
            "linux": {
                "command": "xdg-open"
                }
            },
        "env": {
            "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            },
        "sourceFileMap": {
            "/Views": "${workspaceRoot}/Views"
            }
        },
        {
        "name": ".NET Core Attach",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "attach",
        "processId": "${command.pickProcess}"
        }]
    }
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the launch.json which specifies the file to debug.  I had changed the project to target 1.1 after the launch.json had been generated and it was still specifying the 1.0 dll.